# Filter table based on specific status and same UUIDs

Tags: postgresql, filtering

I would like some help in filtering this table with different account status for same uuids and keep all the uuids where there is at least one Status Active

Sample data:

```
UUID   Status        
  1    Active        
  1    Rejected        
  1    Rejected        
  2    Rejected        
  2    Waitlisted       
  2    Processing        
  3    Active        
  3    Active       
  3    Processing 
  4    Rejected
  4    Processing
```

Expected output:

```
UUID   Status        
  1    Active        
  1    Rejected        
  1    Rejected              
  3    Active        
  3    Active       
  3    Processing
```

I am trying to use some kind of RANK function, but I don't find a way to maintain the rows where there is an UUID with Active, but the status is not Active.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=295e2772ab418fa586407efbadd4c550)

```
SELECT * 
FROM status 
WHERE uuid IN 
    (SELECT uuid FROM status WHERE status = 'Active')
```

1. Selecting the `uuid`s with an `Active` status
2. Selecting the rows with these `uuid`s

Comment: @FlaviodeFalcaoeHelena If it solved your problem please don't forget to accept ( the green hook at the left top of the answer). This shows other users that the topic has finished and solved. If any answer was helpful in any ways please upvote them.